# Is nonce in PHP form and Ajax both necessary?

Tags: plugin-development, nonce

I have a php form which is submitted through jQuery Ajax. Previously i had used nonce with Ajax and PHP form seperately.

Here i am using `wp_nonce_field()` in PHP form. Is it necessary to use `wp_create_nonce()` while localising script and pass this via ajax ? Or the nonce in php form is sufficient ? Using both nonce has any issues ?

Comment: You can just use the nonce from the form.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Thank you. If i use the nonce in ajax, is there in significance for the security ? Or am i moving away from the intended way ?